# Why cant i browse for my gallary on a webpage when using a IPad?

Tags: android, ipad, web

I just had a question about browsing for files on my IPad.

I got a website where you can browse for a picture to upload on the site,
on my cpu it works, on my android mobile it works, but when i come to ipad,
its disabled. How can i enable the function, or why cant i be trusted to upload 
files from my ipad to the web?

Best regrets Empa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS doesn't allow this functionality unfortunately. You'll have to make a native app that does it for you if this is something you need. :)

From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html

> Safari on iOS does not support file uploading, that is,  elements. If your webpage includes an input-file control,
>   Safari on iOS disables it.